# Distributed Password Recovery Using Passware Kit

Tags: networking

In [Passware Kit](http://lostpassword.com/), there is an [option](http://www.lostpassword.com/distributed-password-recovery.htm) offering **distributed** password recovery by brute-force attack which dramatically increases attacks per second. This needs an Agent to be installed on the participating PC, and of course a network connection.

I installed the Main Passware Kit on my own PC, and its Agent on a Laptop. Now, Net connection via cross cable is established, i.e. I can transfer files between PC and Laptop. But, after clicking connect button on the Agent, It starts staring at me and does not do any thing. In other words, I can not use this option while I have every thing needed.

What is wrong with the Agent? What do I do?

Properties,

- Main App: Passware Kit Forensic 12.5
- Agent: Passware Agent 13.1
- PC OS: Win 7 64-bit
- Laptop OS: Win 8 64-bit
- Users: Both Systems Administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passware Kit Agent detects and connects to Passware Kit Server automatically. Your problem is caused by discrepancy between the versions of the Kit and the Agent. Both products should be of the same version, i.e. Passware Kit Forensic 13.1 + Passware Kit Agent 13.1

Comment: Oh! Yes. The only Agent downloadable in the Passware Inc. website is 13.1. Is there any previous version of Agent downloadable?

Comment: Yes, previous versions of the Passware Kit Agent are available upon request. Please, contact Passware Support with your order number for Passware Kit Forensic 12.5, and they will assist you immediately.